# Wi-Fi unavailable on ubuntu 20.04 using the rtl8812au WLAN adapter after installing driver

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, usb

I have been having trouble setting up my wireless adapter with ubuntu 20.04. In the driver that I have most recently installed I get the interface for wireless connection, but can't connect to networks. The type of adapter I have:
When I run

```
sudo lsusb
```

I get

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0951:16a4 Kingston Technology HyperX 7.1 Audio
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2222:0031 MacAlly USB2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. HD Pro Webcam C920
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My device is the obda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor. There are many different repositories for the driver for this usb dongle. I installed the most up to date driver. First I did install many drivers that must not be maintained well and got errors during the build. Or the drivers did nothing at all.

I installed the driver from the following repository: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/blob/v5.6.4.2/README.md

After installing this repository the only thing that changed is I get the interface that allows me to connect to wireless networks. When I go into my settings under Wi-Fi I get the following screen:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uz3yC27XxVzfHOb5OFv8KEtzDsDWhW9s/view?usp=sharing

The above image is the connect to Wi-Fi screen. It is empty it will load forever without finding any networks to connect to(there are certainly wireless networks in range). The title of the page reads Wi-Fi unavailable. Does this mean that there is something wrong with the driver, my wireless Wi-Fi adapter or some config files in my computer?

When I run the command

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

I get:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: 4c:ed:fb:91:fa:f8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-52-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.153 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
  *-network
       physical id: 2
       logical name: t
```

This shows that my Ethernet is connected but its not showing my wireless. Perhaps my wireless is the second section under *-network. There is not much information under that one, however. And I don't know what this information means.

Also I would like to comment that the rtl8812au proprietary driver that you can install using `sudo apt -y install rtl8812au-dkms` doesn't compile with linux kernal according to https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/blob/master/README.md . The gnab rtl8812au repository doesn't seem to work right now either.

A few other commands that chili555 requested:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i 88xx
```

Result:

```
[    7.296982] 88XXau: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.297427] 88XXau: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    7.379054] usb 1-11: 88XXau 74:da:38:e3:77:70 hw_info[107]
[    7.379988] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88XXau
```

Another command:

```
sudo dkms status
```

Result:

```
8812au, 4.2.3: added
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.13.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 470.129.06, 5.13.0-51-generic, x86_64: installedError! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/source/dkms.conf does not exist.

nvidia, 470.129.06, 5.13.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.2.2: added
```

When I run `sudo lshw -C network` without the Ethernet plugged in I get the same output.

When I run `lsmod | grep 88`
I get

```
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
nvidia_uvm           1036288  0
88XXau               2191360  0
snd_pcm               114688  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
cfg80211              888832  1 88XXau
ipmi_msghandler       114688  1 ipmi_devintf
```

My questions are: Why is my Wi-Fi unavailable considering my circumstances? How can I make the Wi-Fi available?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep -i 88xx` Is the result the same with the ethernet detached?

Comment: Let's also see: `lsmod | grep 88` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 . I ran the commands you asked. I have not ran ```sudo dmesg | grep -i 88xx``` yet. Both of the commands returned what looks like an error. I will have to look at the meaning of those errors later tonight. It looks like understanding the output of these commands might lead me somewhere. Thanks for telling me to input these. If you have any thoughts on my problem after seeing these commands let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I'll be happy to help understand the results. Please post the troublesome results and let's see what I can do.

Comment: @chili555 I have posted the results of the lsmod | grep88 command

Comment: Is Secure Boot on or off? Please try again with it off.

Comment: @chili555 secure boot is disabled

Comment: @chili555 it’s been disabled this whole time. I’m thinking about getting a new usb wifi adapter that is more compatible with ubuntu. Do you think this is a good plan?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137605/discussion-between-nick-and-chili555).